# Cloud Foundry Data Flow Server 1.5.1.RELEASE missing dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-skipper

Cloud Foundry Data Flow Server 1.5.1.RELEASE requires ‘spring-cloud-skipper’ and ‘spring-cloud-skipper-client’ version 1.0.5.RELEASE.

The skipper server and skipper client dependencies 1.0.5.RELEASE are missing in maven central repository.

Is there a reason why they are not uploaded in maven central repo ?

If it's a missed, can we please upload them in the maven central repo

(Because of corporate policy we can't pull them from spring repo)

**Spring Cloud Skipper** 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-skipper-server 
**Spring Cloud Skipper Client**
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-skipper-client 
**Spring Cloud Data Flow**
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this! There wasn't a specific reason not to sync in Maven for the Spring Cloud Skipper 1.0.5.RELEASE. It was a miss.

The maven sync process is in place and you will see Spring Cloud Skipper 1.0.5.RELEASE artifacts in a few minutes/hours.

Thanks again!

Comment: I see it now -thanks, however the 1.0.6.RELEASE of spring-cloud-skipper-client is  also missing -  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-skipper-client/